# Can aop:scoped-proxy be used with a generic factory bean?

Tags: java, spring

I built an AbstractFactoryBean implementation which works with generic types, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass<T> extends AbstractFactoryBean<T> {

Class<T> type; // this is injected as a parameter when the factory is used

@Override
protected Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return type;
}

@Override
protected T createInstance() {
    // some logic to create object of type T
    return (T) someObjectResult;
}
```

This works just fine creating beans of any different type. Example:

```
<bean id="whateverBean" class="MyClass" p:type="WhateverBeanClass" />
```

However when I try to use it to create a bean which is ,

```
<bean id="whateverBean" class="MyClass" p:type="WhateverBeanClass" >
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

it fails with the error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create scoped proxy for bean 'scopedTarget.whateverBean': Target type could not be determined at the time of proxy creation.

Based on reading, it kind of seems like the scoped-proxy MUST know what the type is, even before the object is fully initialized. For example, I can't seem to print or log anything in the getObjectType() method when this is happening (was attempting to debug the issue).

Is there any way around this? How can I create scoped proxies with a factory which will know the type of bean it is creating at runtime, but not "pre-runtime" which is when it seems this is occurring?